# Is it possible to create a share Intent from a fragment , so that on dismissing the chooser dialog ,it stays in the calling fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-intent, share

Is it possible to create a share Intent from a fragment , so that on dismissing the chooser dialog ,it stays in the calling fragment itself rather than the parent fragment?

I have a MainFragment which has a ViewPager holding many fragments. Say FragmentA , FragmentB, FragmentC .
Below is some code snippet from MainFragment

```
  override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState).also {
        setupPager()
       }

  private val fragmentList = arrayListOf<BaseFragment<*, *>>(
        FragmentA(),
        FragmentB(),
        FragmentC(),
     )

   private fun setupPager() {
        val adapter = SavvyViewPagerAdapter(
            fragmentList,
            childFragmentManager,
            lifecycle
        )
        binding.mainViewPager.adapter = adapter
        TabLayoutMediator(binding.pageIndicator, binding.mainViewPager) { tab, position ->
            fragmentList[position].titleRes?.let {
                tab.text = getString(it)
            }
        }.attach()
        binding.mainViewPager.setCurrentItem(
                fragmentList.indexOfFirst { it is FragmentB },
                false
```

In FragmentB, there is a recyclerview of some elements . On clicking on any item in the recyclerview , it navigates to FragmentBDetail. This action is given from MainPagerToFragmentBDetail. If the action is given from FragmentB to FragmentBDetail its not working.

Now , in FragmentBDetail  , I am creating a share intent.Below given is the code.

```
        val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, value)
            type = "text/plain"
        }

        val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
        startActivity(shareIntent)
    }
```

This opens the chooser dialog . But on dismissing it , it goes back to MainPagerFragment with FragmentB as the current fragment. On dismissing the dialog , I want it stay in FragmentBDetail itself . How can I achieve this behaviour?

Can someone help?

Comment: `startActivity` is never going to change any state in your own activity - the only way you change fragments is if your code changes what fragment you are on. What do the [Fragment debug logs](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/debugging) say?

Comment: Inside logs I can see that , on dismissing the chooser dialog,  onCreate of MainFragment is first called and then the onCreate of FragmentB

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use `startActivityForResult()` it will help you to solve this problem:

```
    val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, value)
        type = "text/plain"
    }

   val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
   startActivityForResult(shareIntent, SHARE_REQUEST_CODE)
   }
```

then in activity `FragmentBDetail` you can override `onActivityResult`:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

  if (requestCode == SHARE_REQUEST_CODE) {
    // Handle the result of the share intent here
  }
}
```

now, when the chooser dialog is dismissed,  onActivityResult()  will be called in your FragmentBDetail, and you can stay in the fragment.

you must give `SHARE_REQUEST_CODE` a value.

Comment: Tried this . Still its taking me back to MainFragment with FragmentB as the current fragment.